# Ubuntu can't use wifi and bluetooth at the same time

Tags: wireless, bluetooth

I have seen some threads about this problem in the past, but it seems they never get solved, and there are even answers blaming some sort of physical impossibility, which is of course not true, because wifi and bluetooth work together perfectly in windows.

Seriously, how can linux seriously compete against windows, when you have to turn everything off and switch to windows when you simply want to use bluetooth speakers to listen to spotify?

So, for those not familiar with the problem, you generaly can't reliably use bluetooth and wifi at the same time from ubuntu. It will either leave wifi extremely slow, or completely shut it down. So, I don't want to be a complainer, I want to help in some way, but I'm really not an operating systems expert and don't know where to even start contributing to something like this. Can you offer some guideline on what should I do if I don't want to completely give up on ubuntu as a general purpose desktop system?

Obs: there are lots of problems with external devices, but I think people are aware of that, so I'm focusing on the one I think is more absurd/general, which is you simply not being able to use wifi and bluetooth together, independently of the devices. For example, the bluetooth speaker I'm using also offers usb as an option, but ubuntu doesn't recognize the device at all, it doesn't show up in lsusb, etc. So I have two options, either bluetooth or usb, but neither works on ubuntu. But, because usb recognition is more device specific, I'm going with the bluetooth problem at this time.

Comment: This isn't a Ubuntu-specific problem. Both Bluetooth and Wi-Fi use the same 2.4Ghz band, and as such, can interfere with each other. Many routers have a feature called "bluetooth coexistence" which can be enabled to reduce this problem. Google "Bluetooth and Wi-Fi Coexistence" to get more information.

Comment: Hi @heynnema. I addressed that in the question. Bluetooth and Wi-Fi coexist perfectly fine in windows for my notebook. So you can't blame a physical problem as being the cause of this problem that happens in linux only.

Comment: If you have webcam and USB speaker issues, check your BIOS for a USB setting, and see if setting it to "legacy" mode helps to recognize these devices in lsusb.

Comment: Regarding USB, I think there is just no driver available to the speaker in linux.

Comment: My USB speaker works fine. Check the BIOS settings that I specified. Remember to set your Sound output to the speakers. What version Ubuntu?

Comment: Most speakers work fine. Mine doesn't because the driver is not ported. That's (one of the reasons) why bluetooth is important, because you don't need specific drivers for each device.

Comment: It's the same kernel module (snd_usb_audio) no matter what USB speaker. If `lsusb` isn't seeing your speaker, there's something wrong with your speaker. What version Ubuntu?

Comment: You are right on that part. Actually, sometimes lsusb detects the speaker, and displays it as RDA Microelectronics RDA. By a quick search, I concluded that the driver is not ported, because "RDA Microelectronics is a relatively unknown and new chinese chipmaker (...) but nobody has tested or ported this code yet. " as per the https://linux-sunxi.org/Wifi reference. I know that refers to Wifi, but I just think the same thing applies to the speaker too.

Comment: The ubuntu version is 20.04 LTS. So, the speaker (sometimes) appears in lsusb, but, even then, there is no option to set is as a speaker in the sound config of ubuntu. The only option is the built in notebook speaker.

Comment: Are you interested in trying a newer kernel? Let me know, and I'll tell you how. In the mean time, do your Software Updates and get up to Ubuntu 20.04.1. Also, did you check your BIOS settings for USB, as per my previous comment? Show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and tell me the EXACT make/model # of your computer or motherboard.